# Comparing duplicate emails between Accounts and Leads

Tags: apex, query, sosl

I realize accounts and leads are not inherently related, but due to our business process we typically see a large volume of leads that have already been converted into Person Accounts being resubmitted into our system. Same email and everything. While I am working on setting up rules, our users do not have the ability to merge leads through the classic UI.

I am trying to create a visualforce page that displays Leads & Accounts that share a single email. I've been influenced by the below post:

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000936gIAA

The Controller code in here helped me to display duplicate leads within the lead layout after some modification, but I can't figure out how to compare two objects. I thought it would be as simple as creating two lists and iterating over one of them to find a match, but I can't seem to make that work and spit out results on a VF page.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: do you want to search for single email id at a time?

Comment: So I'm trying to search all emails at once..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run SOSL query to find the emailId from Account and Lead together.

Following example will search all the email fields in Account and Lead object and will return Id and Name of corresponding Account and Lead records.

```
String inputEmail = 'firstname.lastname@xyz.com*';
List<List<SObject>> searchList = [FIND :inputEmail 
                                  IN EMAIL FIELDS 
                                  RETURNING Account (Id, Name), 
                                  Lead (Id, Name)];

System.debug('searchList=' + searchList);
Account [] accounts = ((List<Account>)searchList[0]);
Lead [] leads = ((List<Lead>)searchList[1]);
```

Now you can easily display the records in VFP.

You can leverage out of box Duplicate Management and write Duplicate Rules to implement this functionality.

Refer [Manage Duplicate Records in Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=managing_duplicates_overview.htm&language=en_US)

Comment: So I'm trying to search all emails at once.. could I modify this some how to do that? Like all lead emails and accounts that match one of those. Is that possible?

Comment: you can look for Duplicate Management, through configurations